# Return null rows for non-matched values in IN clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns records if found values in the IN clause. The matched records my vary from 0 to 1 and so thus the result of the query. But I want make the count as 5, even if rest rows are filled with NULL. Is there any way I can achieve this?
As, for the given query

```
SELECT categoryID, categoryName
FROM category
WHERE categoryID
IN ( 52, 58, 60 , 62 , 64)
```

I have values for the first 3 ids only and thus the result gives me 3 rows only. But I want the count of result to be 5 and the rest non-satisfying rows filled with null values to make the count.
The current result:

```
CategoryID  CategoryName
52           ABC
58           XYZ
60           DEF
```

The required result

```
CategoryID  CategoryName
52           ABC
58           XYZ
60           DEF
NULL         NULL
NULL         NULL
```

Comment: What is reason for such logic?

Comment: I dont understand why you want to do that...? So if you will type IN ( 52, 58, 60 , 62 , 64, 85, 62, 82) its just returns more null vaules...?

Comment: While it's possible to do it directly in SQL, in most cases, it would be much easier to do it outside of SQL. @Nightmaresux's comment points out one other good question: what do you want to happen when the same ID is specified multiple times?

Comment: @hvd Is it really possible in only-SQL?

Comment: This might be achievable using code but I wanted to know if we could do so directly in plain SQL

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos Yes, and there are already answers showing how. Barmar's answer is almost what I'd have suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with a synthesized table that lists all the category IDs you want:

```
SELECT c.categoryID, c.categoryName
FROM (SELECT 52 AS categoryID
      UNION SELECT 58 UNION SELECT 60 UNION SELECT 62 UNION SELECT 64) AS a
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON a.categoryID = c.categoryID
```

Another way to do this is to create a table that contains all possible category IDs. Then use:

```
SELECT c.categoryID, c.categoryName
FROM allCategories AS a
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON a.categoryID = c.categoryID
WHERE a.categoryID IN (52, 58, 60 , 62 , 64)
```

Comment: The OP wants `categoryID` to be `NULL` too if it's not found, so I think it should be `c.categoryID` rather than `a.categoryID`.

Comment: @hvd Good catch, that's a pretty strange requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Add 5 null rows to the end and just select the first 5 rows.

```
SELECT categoryID, categoryName FROM (
SELECT categoryID, categoryName, 1 as ord 
FROM category
WHERE categoryID
IN ( 52, 58, 60 , 62 , 64)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as categoryID, NULL as categoryName, 0 as ord 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as categoryID, NULL as categoryName, 0 as ord 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as categoryID, NULL as categoryName, 0 as ord  
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as categoryID, NULL as categoryName, 0 as ord  
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as categoryID, NULL as categoryName, 0 as ord  )t 
ORDER BY ord desc LIMIT 0,5;
```

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates, so this doesn't work. Creative answer though, and it can be made to work with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: This also handles the repeated ID case

Comment: @AakashJain You get the same results as with Barmar's first approach: neither will return the same category twice. Barmar's second approach might, depending on how you fill the table.